# Using %Name% variable dynamically with selection tool in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select, iteration

In ArcGIS ModelBuilder is it possible to use a %Name% field value from iterated features in a query and, if so, what syntax should I use?

[image]

Comment: Are you familliar with Python?

Comment: Yes but already solve it with python. Im interestred with use of simple ArcGis Desktop functionalities

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'd use the inline variable in the exact same way you're using it in your output featureclass. `%Name%`.

Inside your Select tool, build up your expression something like:

`'"the_field" = \'%Name%\''`

However -- I question your overall workflow. You're iterating over FeatureClasses and getting the "name" of the featureclass. Your workflow as-is means the Name of the featureclass is going to be used to "select" a row (matches an attribute) in another featureclass.  I suppose that could be valid, it just seems unlikely.

Comment: Yes you got right, this model is simplified just to show the problem i like to solve... :) 
I tested your solution   
'"the_field" = \'%Name%\''   
on my specific case names but the phrase didnt worked ! 
Can You describe how single quotation marks & backslash are changing the execuction of staement ?

Comment: I took the `\'  .. \'` right from the help. You may need to tweak the escapes and slashes depending on your field type to create a proper expression.